# How should I go about getting a wireless connection for my desktop when I have no access to ethernet?

Tags: networking

For context, I recently dual-booted my PC from windows to also have the most recent version of Ubuntu. I am new to linux based distributions, so I am very much not comfortable with it yet.

My current place of living does not support an ethernet connection for whatever reason, so I have been using a USB wifi adapter that works fine. Unfortunately, it did not support linux systems, so I purchased a different adapter that did.

However, this adapter required an internet connection at the time of installation, and the instructions for possible offline installation were described as for "Very advanced users" which I most certainly am not. Does anyone happen to know a simple solution to this issue? I do not mind purchasing a new product.

Edits:

The USB Wifi adapter is a BrosTrend 1200 Mbps Linux USB Wifi adapter.

The `lsusb` command returns the following for this device:

```
ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

The Ubuntu version is 20.04.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information about the USB wifi adapter you have purchased. What is the product, model, etc. ?

Comment: Please insert the device, open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run the command: `lsusb` Pick out your wireless device and next edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: One option: Return the USB adapter, and purchase one that does not need to be "installed." Most are instantly recognized by the Linux kernel and instantly usable to you. Do not support manufacturers and vendors that make this kind of false claim of Linux "compatibility," and do not let them keep your money after they lied to you. Do support reputable vendors who have a generous return policy.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu there are 2 that would be considered the most recent. 20.04 and 20.10

Comment: @user535733 To be fair to the vendors, they do have listed on their page that internet connection is required at install, I just missed it at the time of purchase. Also, their customer service has allowed me to return the product without much argument. Updated the post with asked for edits.

Comment: Your `lsusb` omitted the most important data point; the usb.id. It should be something like: *1a2b:3c4d*. Please include the result.

Comment: Have you tried downloading https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu as zip, than running `make` and `sudo make install` in ternimal (in the extracted .zip archive folder)? This is not so advanced :)

Comment: @Emil First, his is not an rtl8188eu device. That driver won't work. Second, `make` has a great many dependencies that are not included by default in recent Ubuntu versions. What are they? Where can they be downloaded? How is this accomplished without internet access? This is, in fact, *quite* advanced.

Comment: Do you have the original Ubuntu installation DVD or USB? Does your computer have an ethernet port? Have you tried tethering your phone?

Comment: I have the original USB. I didn't think of tethering my phone - will try that later tonight when I have time.

Comment: I will propse an answer that assumes that you can tether your phone. If it turns out that you cannot, I will later amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

Your device is covered by the driver 88x2bu. With your phone tethered, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
./install-driver.sh
```

Detach your tethered phone, reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This device is supported by Linux kernel 6.2 or later. It will work out-of-the-box on Ubuntu 22.04.3 or 23.04 and later.