# How may I get an RTL8211E (USB3 WiFi adapter) working?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

- Distro: - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (fresh install today from scratch)
- Device: - Unknown manufacturer but has the label "AC1200".  It is a
  dual-band 2.4/5GHz type.

I'm trying to install my WiFi device under Ubuntu but the system doesn't appear to recognise it by default.  The device has a RealTek chipset according to `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

When I boot into Ubuntu with this device installed in a USB3 socket, Ubuntu's "WiFi settings" dialog cannot see this device.

I've had this device for about 2 years and have been using it with great success under Windows 10 since then, the bandwidth is excellent (200+ MBit/sec and very stable).

Another WiFi device I have can be recognised and works, but the bandwidth and signal strength is very poor so I'd like to get this  unit working instead, because I know it is far superior.

It would be wonderful to get this device working under Ubuntu, but I have not been able to identify the problem.  I'm not very experienced with WiFi configuration under Linux, but I have taken the following steps so far:

- Updated and upgraded the distro to today's latest releases.
- Tried (and failed) to find an appropriate driver for it.

Can you help me to bring this device online and restore my WiFi connection?

Comment: Please run `lsusb`, find the line identifying your USB device and then [edit] the querstion with that information. RTL8211E is NOT the USB device.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the Q with the correct info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I go about getting a wireless connection for my desktop when I have no access to ethernet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309703/how-should-i-go-about-getting-a-wireless-connection-for-my-desktop-when-i-have-n) Some chipset, the answer should work for you as well, don't mind the awful prose in the question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, yes it worked perfectly!  Thank you kindly for your help.  I guess this should be marked as a duplicate Q for the one you linked to.